# How to update a subdocument in array - mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I can't manage to update the subdocument within the array. I can currently just update the parent-document.

Code where I can update parent-document:

```
router.put('/:id/:bookid', (req, res) => {
  Library.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id //parent-id
  })
    .then(library => {

      //Update with new value
      library.Name = req.body.newName;

      library.save()
        .then(library => {
           //unrelated code
        })
    });
});
```

LibraryScema:

```
const LibarySchema = new Library({
  Name: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  }, 
  books: [BookSchema]
});
```

bookScema:

```
const BookSchema = new Schema({

  title: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  Chapters: [
    {
      chapterTitle: {
        type: String,
        required: false
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

I only aim to update the sub-document, not parent- and sub-document at same time.

**EDIT:**

Earlier attempt:

```
router.put("/:id/:bookid", (req, res) => {
  Library.updateOne(
    { _id: req.params.id, "books._id": req.params.bookid },
    { $set: { "books.$.title": "New value" } }
  );
});
```

The changes don't get saved, no error message.

Comment: What code have you tried using?

Comment: I tried to update with `$set`, but was unsuccessful (must have done something wrong, as this is new to me). And `"$elemMatch"` (worked to `get` that specific sub-document, but couldn't update with that solution, again, could've done something wrong).

Comment: Can you show examples of the code you tried so we can go from there? Updating a `Book` directly even if you got the reference from `Library` shouldn't really be any different, so seeing your exact code may point to the issue.

Comment: @samanime Updated the answer.